# Throwing Shell script's Stored procedure Exception Back to the Caller

Tags: shell, exception, isql

i have a Shell Script A which calls Shell Script B which calls the Stored procedure within ISQL within it. The Exception in Shell Script B's Stored procedure has to be thrown back to the Original Shell Script A. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Don't make us guess, include the smallest amount of code that illustrates your problem. Something like `sqlRes=$(./scriptB args ....)` may be of use but you'll have to carefully control/filter the output from the storedProc inside of scriptB.. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
iSQL > $output_file
status='cat $output_file'
if [$status== "Login Failed"]; then
echo "Login Failed error"
elif  [$status== "Permission Denied"]; then
echo "Permission Denied error"
else [$status== "Connection error"]; then
echo "Connection Denied Error"
fi

 Or

$status='grep "permission denied" $tmp.txt | sed 'g/ /d' | cut -d":" -f2'
echo $status
```

Answer (score 0):

@narasimhakulkami : What do you mean by *throwing an exception* in the context of a POSIX shell script? Aside from using `kill` for some suitable signal, which could be trapped by the receiving process, there is no exception mechanism available.

You could request the exception-catching process to provide its own PID in an environment variable and then do a `kill` on this PID, but of course you can not communicate any additional information with this signal (such as the exact exception message), and it would be a terrible design anyway.

Comment: Suppose if i concatenate output like -isql blah blah blah >$output.txt status echo $output.txt rm $output.txt like this. Is there a way the echo $output.txt can be sent back to calling shell script or Java program??

Comment: This is a completely new question, so I suggest that you make a new one. Catching standard output of a child process can be done from virtually any programming language, so be specific, or ask several questions if you need this to be resolved for more than one language.

Comment: Ok i will give out the solution for this Question myself. Please give me more Points once i do that..

Comment: Your answer seemss ok to me. But if i have to check a string like "connection not established" from stored proc's output, like from temp file, how do i search for such string and echo an output??

Comment: Like i have to grep strings like "connection not established", "port not open" etc and echo an output how to do that??

Comment: Since this looks like a new problem, please ask a new question, where you precisely explain what you want to do, instead of discussing this in a comment. It is not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: i dont think this is a new problem. "The Exception in Shell Script B's Stored procedure has to be thrown back to the Original Shell Script A"--The Original Problem statement talks about this as mentioned in Quote

Comment: First of all, a shell script can't have an exception. The shell language does not have an exception mechanism, unless you count `kill/trap` as one. Hence this way of formulating a question does not make sense, and IMO is the main reason why you should ask a new one. Second, even "throwing" an exception with `kill` does not convey a text with it, and talking about `grep` does not make sense here. If you really want to get answers to your problem, is probably to ask a new question in a clear and understandable way.